# Multiplying then summing the values over 2 tables

Tags: sqlite

I have 2 tables. One called shopping, the other called products.

shopping has columns named Product, Number, Size and Units

my other table, products has the columns, Product, Price, Size and Units

I want to sum the total cost of the items bought on my shopping list taking into account the quantity of the items bought. To do this, I have firstly used the query:

```
SELECT shopping.Product, Number * Price
FROM products INNER JOIN
     shopping
     ON products.Product = shopping.Product;
```

To multiply the number of items bought * Price of the product.

I then wanted to add up the Number*Price total so I used:

```
SELECT shopping.Product, SUM (Number * Price)
FROM products INNER JOIN
     shopping
     ON products.Product = shopping.Product;
```

This does give the correct answer however, for some reason, it also outputs the 'Product' column and prints the name of one of my products, 'Milk' and includes it with the output. How can I get rid of this?

print screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipUkO.jpg

Comment: just dont include it on your select but if you still want it to be grouped then make it a subquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the total for *all* products, then don't include the `product` in the `select`:

```
SELECT SUM(Number * Price)
FROM products INNER JOIN
     shopping
     ON products.Product = shopping.Product;
```

If you want the total for each product, then use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT shopping.Product, SUM(Number * Price)
FROM products INNER JOIN
     shopping
     ON products.Product = shopping.Product
GROUP BY shopping.Product;
```

Comment: I have a problem. I only want it to sum the items that where bought on the shopping list table. what its doing right now is also summing the Price field in my products table

Comment: @Alpha93 . . . Perhaps you should remove `Price` from the select if you don't want it.

Answer (score 0):

well then ill modify the query of Gordon Linoff a bit

if you still want the data to be grouped but you just dont want the product column do this:

```
Select result from
(
SELECT shopping.Product, SUM(Number * Price) as result
FROM products INNER JOIN
     shopping
     ON products.Product = shopping.Product
GROUP BY shopping.Product;
)as x
```

if you DONT want them to be grouped then just dont select it

```
SELECT  SUM(Number * Price) as result
FROM products INNER JOIN
     shopping
     ON products.Product = shopping.Product
```

Comment: I have a problem. I only want it to sum the items that where bought on the shopping list table. what its doing right now is also summing the Price field in my products table